# Pandas - Taking the log of one column with another as base

Tags: pandas, numpy

For example, if I have:

```
A    B    
2    4   
3    5 
6    2
```

I would want a result of:

```
log 2 (4)
log 3 (5)
log 6 (2)
```

I've tried result = math.log(B, A), however this return an error of:

```
Cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

I've had a look around at other questions but couldnt find anything related.
Is this possible in pandas, or would I have too approach this using something such as numpy?

I also had a shot at:

```
result = math.log(B, A).astype(float)
```

however this gave the same error, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be smart about this. Use the properties of log.

```
np.log(df.B) / np.log(df.A)

0    2.000000
1    1.464974
2    0.386853
dtype: float64
```

This works, provided you understand that the logarithm of B with base A is the same as `log B / log A` in any base.

For reference, the result is the same with `math`.

```
df.apply(lambda x: math.log(x[1], x[0]), axis=1)

0    2.000000
1    1.464974
2    0.386853
dtype: float64
```

Comment: yeah nah fair play. Forgot the basic log rules.